# Why am I getting this Hibernate error: HHH000346: Error during managed flush [getPersistenceContext is not valid without active transaction]

Tags: java, hibernate

I have a java method that uses hibernate to make operations on database entities. Here is the method:

```
private void executeQuery(DataEntity dataEntity)
{
    Session session = SessionFactoryUtil.getEntitiesInstance().openSession();
    Transaction transaction = session.beginTransaction();
    try
    {
        session.update(dataEntity);
        transaction.commit();
    }
    catch (RuntimeException e)
    {
        transaction.rollback();
    }
    finally
    {
        session.close();
    }
}
```

Upon executing the `transaction.commit()` call, a RuntimeException is thrown with the following message:

```
ERROR org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl - HHH000346: Error during managed flush [getPersistenceContext is not valid without active transaction]
```

If I change `Session session = SessionFactoryUtil.getEntitiesInstance().openSession();` to `Session session = SessionFactoryUtil.getEntitiesInstance().getCurrentSession();` I am able to successfully commit the transaction and update the entity.

I noticed that `openSession()` returns a `org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl` where `getCurrentSession()` returns a `org.hibernate.internal.ThreadLocalSessionContext`.

This environment is a threaded environment so I need to use `openSession()`.

My final curveball is that the exception is only thrown on certain types of entities; it works for some and fails on others. I am wondering if this even could be a cascade issue or something like that.

Edit: the exception is thrown during the flush() call inside commit(). I get the exception if I call flush() manually as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up having a HibernateInterceptor that hid the problem. It hit the database in a non traditional way that was fine with `getSession()` but not `openSession()`.